# Is a busy-loop the best way for my async function to not complete until bluetooth scan completes?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, bluetooth

I have an async function in my Flutter app that scans for bluetooth devices. I would prefer that the async function does not complete, until the bluetooth scan completes.

I have implemented this with a busy-loop that block until the scan is complete, and checks every 500ms if this is the case.

Is this the best way to do this in dart? Is this problematic?

```
var stream = FlutterBlue.instance.scan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 10)); 
stream.listen((ScanResult result) async {
  if (result.device.name == _expectedName) {
    try {
      await result.device.disconnect();
      await result.device.connect();
      _scannedDevice = result.device;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
});

while (_scannedDevice == null && await FlutterBlue.instance.isScanning.first) {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
}

if (_scannedDevice == null) {
  return DeviceConnectResult.deviceNotFound;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for was 'await for' loop.

An 'await for' loop will process each event in a stream, and synchronously suspend execution until the stream is complete.

```
var stream = FlutterBlue.instance.scan(timeout: Duration(seconds:10));
await for (var scanResult in stream) {
  if (scanResult.device.name == _expectedName) {
    try {
      await scanResult.device.disconnect();
      await scanResult.device.connect();
      device = scanResult.device;
      await FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When browsing the API documentation for FlutterBlue I came across the [`startScan`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue/latest/flutter_blue/FlutterBlue/startScan.html) method that seems to be a good solution for your problem.

> Starts a scan and returns a future that will complete once the scan
> has finished. To observe the results while the scan is in progress, listen to the scanResults stream

```
FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults.listen((ScanResult result) async {
  if (result.device.name == _expectedName) {
    try {
      await result.device.disconnect();
      await result.device.connect();
      _scannedDevice = result.device;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
});
await FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 10));
```